# InvokeRepeating() limitation? (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to instantiate game objects at a given rate. Usually InvokeRepeating would do the job, except for the fact that this time **I do not want the rate to be a constant** when instantiating the objects.

I understand that InvokeRepeating should be called inside the Start() portion of the code. So my question is: Is there any way to get around this problem or will I have to take a different approach?

Thank you all in advance!

Here is a portion of the code that illustrates the problem I am talking about:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class InstantiateLARSpider : MonoBehaviour {

public float instantiateRate;
public GameObject xSpider;
private Vector3 position;
public float minimumSpeed;

void Start () {

    // instantiateRate is a variable that I want to modify over time.  
    InvokeRepeating("NewSpider", 1.0f, instantiateRate);
}

void NewSpider ()
{
    position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Random.Range(-4.5f,4.5f), 0);
    Debug.Log("Instantiated");
    var Spider = Instantiate(xSpider, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    if(transform.position.x>=11.0f){
        Spider.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(-1.0f * Random.Range(minimumSpeed, 6.0f), 0.0f);
    }
    else if(transform.position.x<=-11.0f){
        Spider.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(1.0f * Random.Range(minimumSpeed, 6.0f), 0.0f);
    }
    //I was thinking about increasing the instantiateRate by 0.1 every time a Spider is instantiated.
    instantiateRate -= 0.1f;
    minimumSpeed += 0.1f;
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of using `InvokeRepeating`, could you just use `Invoke` at the end of your `NewSpider` method? This way you'd be able to choose the delay each time.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! They work perfectly. I decided to accept aqez answer since you can only accept one. However Chris answer is perfectly functional and clever. Also it would be very nice to know whether one of them consumes more resources than the other. In the aplication I am making that doesnt really matter, but I am interested in knowing for future occasions. @aqez

Comment: Something worth noting is chaining together Invoke calls may eventually lead to a stack overflow or memory issues - depending on if Invoke returns immediately or after running the method you're trying to invoke. If it is the latter, you will fill the call stack with potentially infinite recursion depending on NewSpider's implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, changing instantiateRate after it has been used to call InvokeRepeating doesn't actually change the copy of the argument that InvokeRepeating recieved. To mirror InvokeRepeating's functionality, you could end up with something similar to the following:

```
    public delegate void MethodToCall(); //A delegate - you can pass in any method with the signature void xxx() in this case!
    public IEnumerator InvokeRepeatingRange(MethodToCall method, float timeUntilStart, float minTime, float maxTime)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeUntilStart);
        while (true)
        {
            method(); //This calls the method you passed in
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(minTime, maxTime))
        }
    }
```

I don't have Unity on this machine so I can't verify that that compiles (mostly the Random.Range part, the rest I'm pretty familiar with). The way you would call this in your case is:

```
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(InvokeRepeatingRange(NewSpider, 2, 5, 10));
    }

    void NewSpider() //Since NewSpider matches the signature void xxx(), we can pass it to InvokeRepeatingRange()
    {
        //...
    }
```

Tweak the parameters and logic inside of InvokeRepeatingRange to get the desired effect, perhaps:

```
    public delegate void MethodToCall();
    public IEnumerator InvokeRepeatingDecreasingTime(MethodToCall method, float timeUntilStart, float minTime, float maxTime)
    {
        float currentTime = maxTime;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeUntilStart);
        while (currentTime >= minTime)
        {
            method();
            currentTime -= .1f;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(currentTime);
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this gives you a new way to think about this pattern of doing things and answers your original question as well.

Edit: updated for better variable names and a little more explanation.
      added StartCoroutine() call as mentioned in comment!

Comment: Solid answer, although coroutines in C# require a [`StartCoroutine` call](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html).

Comment: I **knew** I was forgetting something, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using InvokeRepeating, why don't you do it in the Update method?  You can use a field to keep track of the last time you created a new object.

```
private float lastTimeCreated;
private float timeBetweenCreation;
...

void Start()
{
    // Initial time between object creation
    this.timeBetweenCreation = 1f;
}

void Update()
{
    float now = Time.time;

    // Check if it's time to create a new object
    if (now - this.lastTimeCreated > this.timeBetweenCreation)
    {
        this.NewSpider();

        // Object created, so set new lastTimeCreated
        this.lastTimeCreated = now;

        // Some logic to change your timeBetweenCreation.  Do it here or in NewSpider().
        // this.timeBetweenCreation = ...
    }
}

void NewSpider ()
{
    // Mostly what you had
    position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, Random.Range(-4.5f,4.5f), 0);
    Debug.Log("Instantiated");
    var Spider = Instantiate(xSpider, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    if(transform.position.x>=11.0f){
        Spider.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(-1.0f * Random.Range(minimumSpeed, 6.0f), 0.0f);
    }
    else if(transform.position.x<=-11.0f){
        Spider.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(1.0f * Random.Range(minimumSpeed, 6.0f), 0.0f);
    }

    // Some logic to change your timeBetweenCreation.  Do it here or in Update().
    // this.timeBetweenCreation = ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to instantiate at a changing rate, I would use `Invoke` instead of `InvokeRepeating`:

```
void Start () {
    Invoke("NewSpider", 1.0f);
}

void NewSpider () {
    ...
    Invoke("NewSpider", instantiateRate);
}
```

`NewSpider` will first get invoked within `Start`. Then, at the end of your `NewSpider` method, `NewSpider` will be invoked again with whatever `instantiateRate` is set to.